# How can I translate text inside controller in Spring Framework 3?

Tags: spring, localization, internationalization

I need to send email confirmation, so now I have to localize sent message. I have initialized i18n in spring and now it works perfectly in jsp pages, but how can I use it in my controllers?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you are using annotated controllers you can autowire the MessageSource and add the locale of the request like this:

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class MailController
{
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mail/send", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView sendEmail(Locale locale)
    {
        String[] args = { "Mr.", "X" };
        // E.g. message.code="Dear {0} {1}"
        String mailmessage = messageSource.getMessage("message.code", args, locale);
        // Do something
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer and question twice... Thanks, Daff and newbie!

Comment: Does the usage of `@Scope("request")` here mean that a new instance of the controller is created for every request?

Comment: Amr Mostafa: this is a little off topic but yes. A new instance is created for  every request. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other